# Google map API key problem in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I have generated a Google Maps API key for my Android application. It works perfectly fine.
Next, I want to use Google Maps in another application. So, what I did was simply copy paste the Google Maps API key from the first application's XML file to the second application's XML file. Strangely, the map view doesn't display anything but empty grids in the second application.

Note that I've allowed all the permissions in the manifest file.

Also, I want to know if the map key is portable between systems as the debug.keystore file changes between systems. I tried generating another map API key for my second application. But, that didn't quite help because Google gave me the same map key.

Comment: What is your LogCat showing???

Comment: I don't quite know what the problem is but I removed my api_key from the layout file(under the mapView tag) and refferenced it by a string in the Strings.xml file and it seemed to work. There's something wrong with eclipse. It acts weirdly at times.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the code to version 3 of the API. This does not need a key.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Maps JavaScript API v3 (which the current tags for the question indicate you are), then you do not need an API key for those maps.  v2 required an API key, but v2 is deprecated.

(If you are using a non-JavaScript API for Maps, the google-maps-api-3 tag should be removed from the question.)